# Update select statement from subselect statement result array

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a query that I have been working on for a little bit, and I can kind of understand why it's in error, however I cannot seem to figure out how to make everything function.

My setup looks like this.

I have a database table that contains the a list of sites

```
table name: websites

column name within websites: 
domain_name
------------------
site1234.mydomain.com
site1235.mydomain.com
site1256.mydomain.com
site1257.mydomain.com
site1258.mydomain.com
```

What I am looking to do is to change everything after the subdomain section so ie: .mydomain.com -> .mynewdomain.com

I have the query to get the first subdomains just fine.

```
SELECT split_part(domain_name, '.', 1) AS site_name FROM websites;
```

So I understand that this needs to be in a subselect, but I am not sure what I am missing. My select/subselect query looks like this.

```
UPDATE websites SET domain_name = site_name || '.mynewdomain.com' FROM (SELECT split_part(domain_name, '.', 1) FROM websites) AS site_name WHERE domain_name LIKE '%.mydomain.com';
```

I understand why it is in error because my first query returns more than one row, so it sees the data mismatch, I know I need to some how loop through each result in the subselect and use that value in the initial select, but I don't know what syntax I would need to make this function.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

-H

Comment: Could you review my answer and let us know if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE websites
SET domain_name = t.site_name || '.mynewdomain.com' FROM
(
    SELECT split_part(domain_name, '.', 1) AS site_name
    FROM websites
) t
WHERE domain_name LIKE '%.mydomain.com';
```

Comment: Code worked perfectly, I figured I would have to set two aliases, but I wasn't able to get it to work just right, oh well, thank you!